# Connect to a local database via user input

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a program where on a click event SQL will open and connect to a server instance and database however. I am wanting to make to program a bit more dynamic and allow user input but I am struggling to get this to work as wanted.

The old code is as follows and this works:

```
Process.Start("ssms.exe", "-S .\\SQLEXPRESS -d master -E ");
```

I tried the following but this just opens SQL but states will not use the details enterd to connect to a database.

```
Process.Start("ssms.exe", DataBaseNameInput.Text);
```

**Edit**

The error SQl shows is `The following files where specified on the command line: These files could not be found and will not be loaded.`

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for ssms?  Is that a valid way of using it?  Have you don't *any* research?

Comment: How are you collecting the input?  What is your UI?  Can you also include any exceptions/errors?

Comment: @rory.ap I have had a look at a fair few documents but I am unable to find  anything that relates to what I am trying :(, I mean maybe that means I can't but I thought someone on here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @StinkyTowel, This is just from a text box allow the user to input the desired server address.

Comment: How do you anticipate your application actually working if you allow the user to type in the address of their sql server?

Comment: @SeanLange, The idea is that this program will be used on a few different machines. So the user will be able to enter the local DB address in the text box and then press the button that holds the click even. This will then open SQL and connect to the address the user has entered. The fist bit on code is how it works currently and this is fine however this is only good for that one machine.

Comment: Do the users have SSMS installed locally?

Comment: @JacobH, Yeah they do.

Comment: Something sounds far left of center with your whole concept here. Most users are not going to know or care about the location of a database server. And your code is going to have to be really robust to allow this freedom. You will have to constantly check for existing objects in the database. This seems like a classic XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I do agree with @SeanLange it seems like this could be done with connection strings or even a different approach entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you would need to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder()`, this allows you to build a string whitch can then be passed.

```
        var Connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        Connection.DataSource = ServerNameTextBox.Text;
        Connection.InitialCatalog = DatabaseTextbox.Text;
        Connection.UserID = UserNameTextBox.Text;
        Connection.Password = PasswordTextBox.Text;
        var connString = Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was done by the following information

[Ssms Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility)